# Android Studio databinding android:text error = <expr> expected, got '''

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, viewmodel, android-databinding, mobile-development

```
android:text="@{String.valueOf(detailedPostVM.postLiveData.likedUsers.size)+'people liked'}"

android:text="@{detailedPostVM.alreadyLiked ? 'LIKED' : 'LIKE'}"
```

I am trying to use databinding in android studio with kotlin. But it gives this error:

> `<expr> expected, got ''`

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.

```
android:text='@{String.valueOf(detailedPostVM.postLiveData.likedUsers.size)+" people liked"}'
```

Just start with single '.